# PDO rowcount return value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP's PDO (with mysql server) to update a table. Something similar to the query:

```
UPDATE  game g
SET     g.some_field=1
WHERE   g.game_id=:game_id AND g.is_finished=1
AND     (g.player1=:player_id OR g.player2=:player_id)
LIMIT   1
```

executed like this:

```
$psResult = $ps->execute();
if( !$psResult ){
    // database error
} else if( $ps->rowCount() <= 0 ){
    // no row was updated.
}
```

Now the else-if statement that does the rowCount() check can be 0 when:

- There is **no record** with a game id equal to `:game_id` which has `is_finished` set to 1 and has `:player_id` as either `player1` or `player2`.
- There was such a record but the `some_field` was already set to 1.

I need to distinguish these in order to return a correct error/value. For example return true if the field was set to 1 or already had 1 and return false if no record was matched.

How can I do this? Is there another way then doing an extra query?

Comment: An `update` updates or doesn't and it tells you if it did or didn't.  It can't tell you that it updated but there was no need because the update didn't change anything.  Maybe you want `WHERE g.some_field<>1`? Or if you need to know, do a `SELECT` first.

Comment: Ok so I guess there's no way to distinguish matched rows from affected rows then. The WHERE clause doesn't really change anything. I will use a select statement then. Thanks :)

Comment: @AbraCadaver is right. you should better set `where g.some_field<>1` that will guarantee that if your `row_count` return 1 = there was update done

Comment: @KimAlexander: Yes, but I think, for whatever reason they want to know if all conditions matched but it didn't need to be updated.

Comment: to all conditions by default we mean `WHERE ... AND... AND... AND some_field<>1` that what exactly was suggested by @AbraCadaver

Comment: @KimAlexander rowCount will in any case only return 1 if an update is done. So when a row matched but some_field was already 1 then rowCount is 0. I don't think `WHERE g.some_field<>1` adds something to that. The reason I want to know whether a row was matched is that I can give feedback on whether the update affected no rows because the game id didn't exist or because the field that was being updated already had that value.

Comment: I can agree with you, but just 50%. if you don't use `some_field<>1` condition your update will bring 1 even if somefield was 1 before your update, if you change that - your request will bring 0 if some_field was 1 before your request. So we have a difference here. But it is up to you and your particular case. You can say that this difference is useless for you. I can'tsay anything against that is your application and your logic, not mine. Anyway good luck with development